# Populate a variable instance once calculations in a previous row are finished

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to calculate the final number of unprocessed claims after each month. First, I calculate a `total` number of claims to process: it's a last month's `backlog` + any `new_claims` coming in the current month. Then, in order to calculate a number of `close_claims` I multiply that number by a `closed_total_ratio` and take that away from the `total`. My final variable is `open_claims` which should automatically feed into `backlog` as soon as it's calculated:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(date = seq(from = lubridate::as_date('2018-01-01'), to = lubridate::as_date('2018-06-01'), by = 'months'),
             backlog = c(120, rep(NA, 5)),
             new_claims =sample(c(10,20,30), 6, replace = T),
             closed_open_ratio = rep(0.2, 6),
             open_claims = rep(NA, 6))
df

set.seed(1)
solution <- tibble(date = seq(from = lubridate::as_date('2018-01-01'), to = lubridate::as_date('2018-06-01'), by = 'months'),
                   backlog = c(120, 104, 99, 95, 100, 88),
                   new_claims =sample(c(10,20,30), 6, replace = T),
                   total = c(130, 124, 119, 125, 110, 118),
                   closed_total_ratio = rep(0.2, 6),
                   closed =  c(26, 25, 24, 25,22,24),
                   open_claims = c(104, 99, 95, 100,88, 94)
)
solution
```

The thing is, if I apply something like this:

```
df %>%
  mutate(total = backlog[1] +cumsum(new_claims),
         closed = closed_open_ratio* total,
         open_claims = total - cumsum(closed)) %>%
  select(backlog, new_claims, total, closed_open_ratio, closed, open_claims)
```

I fail to move `open_claims` back to the `backlog`. What would be a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `purrr::accumulate` to carry forward the still opened claims starting from the backlog on Day 1. `cumsum` and `cumprod` are the most common examples of this type of computation but in this case we need something more complex than `cumsum` because a proportion of the claims get closed every day.

Let `p` be the probability of closing (a constant). Let `q=1-p` be the probability of not closing.

1. For Day 1 we have `backlog + new_claims` claims. Let's call the
   total `x1`. Then at the end of Day 1 we have `q*x1` claims still
   open.
2. Then for Day 2 we have the previously open claims, `q*x1`,
   plus some new ones, `x2`, and at the end of Day 2 we have `q*(q*x1 + x2)` claims still open. Let's look at one more day to make it clear.
3. For Day 3 we have the previously open claims plus those received
   that day and at the end of Day 3 we have `q*(q*(q*x1 + x2) + x3)` claims still open.

This is the kind of sequential computation we can perform with `purrr::accumulate`.

```
p_close <- 0.2

df %>%
  # Not very elegant but need to add backlog to the first-day claims
  mutate(new_claims = if_else(row_number() == 1, 
                              new_claims + backlog, new_claims)) %>%
  # This function computes p*(p*(p*(p*x1 + x2) + x3) + x4) .....
  mutate(tot_claims = accumulate(new_claims, function(x, y) (1-p_close)*x + y)) %>%
  # Simple vectorized product to split the total claims into open and closed
  mutate(open_claims = (1-p_close) * tot_claims,
         closed_claims = p_close * tot_claims) %>%
  # The backlog is the previous days opened claims
  mutate(backlog = if_else(row_number() == 1, 
                           backlog, lag(open_claims)))
```

The above computation assumes that the probability `p_close` of closing a claim is the same every day. But you can work with `purrr::accumulate2` to provide both a vector of claims and a vector of closing probabilities.

This accumulation is a little more complex so let's define it separately.

```
accumulate_claims <- function(new_claims, closed_open_ratio) {
  f <- function(x, y, p) (1-p)*x + y
  # head(p, -1) drops the last probability. We actually don't need it here
  # as right now we are computing the sequential sums of previously opened
  # claims + the new claims for the day
  x <- accumulate2(new_claims, head(closed_open_ratio, -1), f)
  unlist(x)
}

df %>%
  # Not very elegant but need to add backlog to the first-day claims
  mutate(new_claims = if_else(row_number() == 1, new_claims + backlog, new_claims)) %>%
  # This function computes p4*(p3*(p2*(p1*x1 + x2) + x3) + x4) .....
  mutate(tot_claims = accumulate_claims(new_claims, closed_open_ratio)) %>%
  # Simple vectorized product to split the total claims into open and closed
  mutate(open_claims = (1-closed_open_ratio) * tot_claims,
         closed_claims = closed_open_ratio * tot_claims) %>%
  # The backlog is the previous days opened claims
  mutate(backlog = if_else(row_number() == 1, backlog, lag(open_claims)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant, but I think it works. There are some differences with your solution, but also the new_claims column is different:

```
df <- tibble(date = seq(from = lubridate::as_date('2018-01-01'), to = lubridate::as_date('2018-06-01'), by = 'months'),
             backlog = c(120, rep(NA, 5)),
             new_claims =sample(c(10,20,30), 6, replace = T),
             closed_open_ratio = rep(0.2, 6),
             open_claims = rep(NA, 6))

df <- data.frame(df)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$open_claims[i] <- (df$backlog[i] + df$new_claims[i]) - ((df$backlog[i] df$new_claims[i]) * df$closed_open_ratio[i])
  if (i < nrow(df)) {
     df$backlog[i + 1] <- (df$backlog[i] + df$new_claims[i]) - ((df$backlog[i] + df$new_claims[i]) * df$closed_open_ratio[i])
   }
 }
 df
        date  backlog new_claims closed_open_ratio open_claims
1 2018-01-01 120.0000         10               0.2   104.00000
2 2018-02-01 104.0000         20               0.2    99.20000
3 2018-03-01  99.2000         10               0.2    87.36000
4 2018-04-01  87.3600         20               0.2    85.88800
5 2018-05-01  85.8880         30               0.2    92.71040
6 2018-06-01  92.7104         20               0.2    90.16832
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, @Santiago Capobianco, your solutions does work if you set the same random seed. However, I was hoping to avoid for loops here as I'll be iterating over big data frames. Hope you don't mind if I wait if there are any alternative approaches before I accept? Thanks for help!

Comment: `mutate` does everything vectorized and because your next calculations depends on the previous one this is not possible and you have to use a for loop.

Comment: Sure, there must be a better way indeed. I also tried an apply over rows, but I think any way of vectorization needs to use and argument that does not change.

Answer (score 2):

Cześć Kasiu! I think we can't avoid iteration, if result in the next row depends on result from the previous one. You wrote "I'll be iterating over big data frames" so the best way to save some time is to use `Rcpp`. You need to create new "C++ File" (it's integrated with RStudio) with the following code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame forKasia(DataFrame DF) {

  IntegerVector backlog = DF["backlog"];
  IntegerVector new_claims = DF["new_claims"];
  NumericVector closed_open_ratio = DF["closed_open_ratio"];
  IntegerVector open_claims = DF["open_claims"];
  int n = backlog.size();
  IntegerVector total = IntegerVector(n);
  IntegerVector closed = IntegerVector(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    total[i] = backlog[i] + new_claims[i];
    closed[i] = round(total[i] * closed_open_ratio[i]);
    open_claims[i] = total[i] - closed[i];

    if (i < n - 1) {
      backlog[i + 1] = open_claims[i];
    }

  }

  return DataFrame::create(
    _["date"] = DF["date"],
    _["backlog"] = backlog,
    _["new_claims"] = new_claims,
    _["total"] = total,
    _["closed_open_ratio"] = closed_open_ratio,
    _["closed"] = closed,
    _["open_claims"] = open_claims
  );

}
```

Then source it and run:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp('forKasia.cpp')
forKasia(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to tackle the sequential nature of the computation is with recursion, calculating the inital open claims using the first row of the dataset, and then repeating the call using the remaining rows.

```
calc_open_claims <- function(current_backlog, new_claims, closed_open_ratio) {
  (current_backlog + new_claims) * (1 - closed_open_ratio)
}

open_claims <- function(weekly_changes, accumulator) {

  if (nrow(weekly_changes) == 0) return(accumulator)

  new_backlog <- calc_open_claims(last(accumulator), 
                                  weekly_changes$new_claims[1], 
                                  weekly_changes$closed_open_ratio[1])
  accumulator = c(accumulator, new_backlog)
  open_claims(weekly_changes[-1, ], accumulator)
}

open_claims(df, 120)

# Wrapper to kick it off and align result 
open_claims_wrapper = function(df) {
  starting_backlog <- df$backlog[1]
  oc <- open_claims(df, starting_backlog)  # starting_backlog seeds the accumulator
  oc <- oc[-1]  # lop off the starting backlog
  mutate(df, open_claims = oc)
}
open_claims_wrapper(df)
```